# find rows that has values only in certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have a data frame like this:

```
>>> o1.columns
```

Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'm1', 'm2', 7, 'm3', 8, 'm4', 9], dtype='object')

I want to find the rows that has data only and only in m1,m2,m3 and m4 but the rest of the columns is nan or empty. Is it possible? I have tried more or less like the following:

```
>>> o11=o1[(1==@nan) && (2==@nan) && (3==@nan) && (4==@nan) && (5==@nan) && (6==@nan) && (7==@nan) && (8==@nan) && (9==@nan) && (o1.m1!=@nan) && (o1.m2!=@nan) && (o1.m3!=@nan) && (o1.m4!=@nan)]
```

But it doesn't work. Tried "pd.query also". Maybe I am missing very simple thing. Thanks for your help.
Best Regards
Zillur

Comment: What if any of m1, m2, m3 or m4 have NaN values? Would you still want those rows to be returned?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah. Actually I need rows that have values any of these 4 columns and no values in all other columns.

Comment: So basically its okay for any/all of `m1`, `m2`, `m3`, `m4` to have `NaN` values? Or do you need atleast one non-null value in any of these columns? Please be clear.

Comment: Check out the dataframe I have provided in my answer and tell me which rows you would want returned, and your logic behind it.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted the rows that has values any of these 4 columns and no values in all other columns.  So basically its okay for any/some of m1, m2, m3, m4 to have NaN values. Does it make sense?

Comment: Thank you. I just edit the 2nd line of your command. "m2=o1[['m1','m2','m3','m4']].isna().sum(axis=1)<4". That's it.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes. It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Call `notna`/`isna` and `any`/`all` along the first axis, AND the masks and index.

```
cols = ['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4']
diff = df.columns.difference(cols).tolist()

df[df[cols].notna().any(1) & df[diff].isna().all(1)]
```

This is assuming you want ALL the data in `m*` to not be null, and vice versa.

Comment: AAAAAAHHH @coldspeed

Comment: Elegant af, as always :)

Answer (score 1):

Given a dataframe df as:

```
df = 
         1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   m1   m2    m3   m4
    0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
    1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
    2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
    3  NaN    4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.5  1.7  1.23  1.6
    4  NaN    1  NaN  NaN    1  NaN  NaN  NaN   12  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
    5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
    6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1  1.2   1.2  1.5
    7  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
    8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
    9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
```

We want only row at index = 6 to be returned (as per your requirement):

```
m1 = df[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]].isna().sum(axis = 1) == 9

m2 = df[['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4']].isna().sum(axis = 1) == 0

df[m1 & m2]
```

Output:

```
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9 m1   m2   m3   m4
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1  1.2  1.2  1.5
```